# Any way to run an iPhone simulator on a web app?

Tags: ios

Is there an iPhone simulator plugin anywhere? We want to load some of our apps to our demo website for marketing purposes.

Does anyone know of anything that can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Nope, cannot be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible, unless Apple releases some sort of plugin itself (which I can confidently say, will never ever happen). The closest you can get is to use some mockup templates/scripts to simulate the behavior of your app with Javascript/CSS/HTML5 canvas.

You can look into some web apps which provide similar functionality. Of course, not like the real thing, but at least, they can be a good starting point and even complete solutions for relatively simple projects. I've googled `web iphone app mockup` and got a few results: https://www.fluidui.com/editor/live/ or http://iphonemockup.lkmc.ch/ may be helpful.